# JavaScript Magic 8 Ball - Unexpected '{'

Tags: javascript

This is the very beginning of my Magic 8 Ball code for Javascript.

It keeps on giving me this error:

> '{' unexpected

What should I do?

```js
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
console.log("Welcome " + name);

var yn = console.log("Would you like to shake the eight ball?");

switch (yn); {
  case: true;
  console.log('Ok...');
};
```

Comment: You have `;` in front of  `{`

Comment: remove the semicolon on the first line, in front of the opening brace

Comment: It’s also `case thing:`, not `case : thing;`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. It should be

```
switch(yn){
    case true: 
        console.log('Ok...'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong here, starting with the syntax error `;` after `switch()`.

SUGGESTED ALTERNATIVE:

```
if (confirm("Would you like to shake the eight ball?")) {
    // Shake
} else {
    // Rattle and Roll
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `switch` syntax is wrong.

This is the right way:

```
switch (yn) { 
    case true: 
        console.log('Ok...');
        break;
};
```

Also added a `break` statement at the end of the `case` because if there are more `case`s  before the matching `case`, they will also be executed.

---

Guessing for the variable name `yn`, you probably plan to only have your `switch` to handle both `true` and `false` cases, for that situation you should use an `if`.

It would look like this:

```
if (yn) {
    console.log('Ok...');
} else {
    //your code for "false" goes here
}
```

Or if you don't want to do anything when `false` just skip the `else` block entirely, like this:

```
if (yn) {
    console.log('Ok...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your switch has a semicolon. Removing it will fix the problem. How it should be: `switch() {}` how it currently is: `switch(); {}`